# how are files named in datanode | naming conventions of file in datanode hadoop

Tags: hadoop

Please let me know how/or on what basis the files are named in the datanode?

I did a copyFromLocal of a file greater than 64MB and found that it created two set of files. a meta file and a portion of actual file.

how are files named in datanode? What is the algorithm used by hadoop architecture to name this file?
blk_-861882337543881015_1251.meta
blk_-861882337543881015
blk_-1127355763020627217_1252.meta
blk_-1127355763020627217

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually two types of files are being written into a datanode. One will contain the actual raw data with the file name as `blk_<64 bit block ID>`. It is just a notation of that block id.

And the other file will contain the metadata information with a header in it which contains information like version,type, and the checksum. This checksum would be useful when a read operation is performed on this block, while reading if it doesn't match this checksum then error will be thrown. And the filename will be named as `blk_<64 bit blockid>_<file_generation_stamp>.meta`.

The file generation stamp is used to tell if the datablock was created before or after the last NameNode "fsimage" checkpoint.  If before the last checkpoint then this number would be less then what is stored in the "fsimage" binary file. This info would be helpful when the content from fsimage is committed to the namenode during startup.

So suppose your replication factor is 3. So your data will be stored in 3 datanodes and so each block will have a metafile. So totally you have 3 replicas(raw data file) + 3 meta files.

Comment: Thanks Vignesh, also when can you clarify on another question? If we keep the replication factor as 3, does it create 3 copies/replica of both meta and data file in 3 different nodes + actual copy of the file loaded?  I mean to ask if there will be totally 4 copies?

Comment: Updated my answer(last paragraph) . Any more queries?

Comment: I agree it creates 3 copies of data, but if do a copyFromLocal of a file from local file system to hdfs, then in this case will there be 4 copies? the one I copied and 3 copies of the same in different data nodes as the replication factor is 3?

Comment: There is nothing different when you write to HDFS between copyfromlocal and put except copyfromlocal is more restricted to a local system than put, in both the cases you will end up only with 3 copies in datanode.